# Weyl group of a K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces, weyl-group

I am wondering wether the action of the Weyl group $W_X$ of a K3 surface $X$ is transitive on the sets of curves of fixed genus.

Suppose $W_X$ is non-trivial. Given two curves $C,C'$ of genus $g\geq2$ on $X$, does there exists an element $\sigma$ of the Weyl group such that $\sigma C =C'$ ?

Comment: Certainly not in general: there are K3 surfaces with Picard number >1 containing no $(-2)$-curves.

Comment: ok sorry, let me edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except in trivial cases, this is never true. The closure of the Kähler cone of $X$ is a fundamental domain for $W_X$ (see Barth et al., *Compact complex surfaces*, ch. VIII, Prop. 3.10)). Thus if your curves $C$ and $C'$ are ample (which just means that they meet all $(-2)$-curves), they are not conjugate under $W_X$.

Comment: Still no. Actually the ampleness condition is superfluous: your curves are always *nef*, i.e. in the closure of the ample cone. Thus the above argument still applies.